# Why does my GAS sort script duplicate all rows?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

First, can I just thank everyone here. I've hacked a bit of javascript over the years based solely on the Q&A here on Stack Overflow. Appreciated.

Now I'm have my first bash at Google Apps Script, and my attempt is leading to some unwanted behavior.

```
function sortFormResponses1() {  
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Projects");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IGNORE ME");

sheet1.sort(2);  

var source1 = sheet1.getRange("B2:B300");
source1.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 3, 3, 2, 300);

var source2 = sheet1.getRange("G2:G300");
source2.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 2, 2, 2, 300);

var source3 = sheet1.getRange("J2:J300");
source3.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 4, 4, 2, 300);

var source4 = sheet1.getRange("O2:Q300");
source4.copyValuesToRange(sheet2, 5, 7, 2, 300);  

sheet2.sort(2);
}
```

When the final `sort` line is commented out, the rows that end up in Sheet2 equal those in Sheet1. With the final sort line, all rows in Sheet2 are duplicated. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it helps I've found if one doesn't define the same function in slightly different scripts. Doh.